Can I add noise to WorldLinearVel and WorldAngularVel to simulate a real world scenario when the controller i'm using doesn't provide speed feedback?
I am trying to generate some odometry from my robot. It is using the libSimpleTrackedVehicle plugin which only provides the track speed which does not constantly update and only changes if there is a new cmd_vel message. The libSimpleTrackedVehicle plugin does not use a joint controller (from what I can see) and instead uses friction and forces to push the robot. With that said, I have been using a combination of the gazebo functions WorldPos, WorldLinearVel and WorldAngularVel to get the  location of the robot in simulation. I also would like a relative odom position to simulate a real world scenario. I have used std::normal_distribution to generate some random gaussian noise for both the WorldAngularVel and WorldLinearVel. I have also removed WorldPose and now estimate the position based on the two velocity values and time. Is there anything else I can do to make this more real world accurate?
TLDR; Can I add noise to WorldLinearVel and WorldAngularVel to simulate a real world scenario when the controller i'm using doesn't provide speed feedback?
